# Just want to refresh pivot tables without refreshing queries

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a vba only to refresh the local pivot tables. Since the pivot tables are getting data from a power query which links to a password locked excel file. In the past few days, I managed to write a vba to open the external excel file to refresh my query.

After refresh, my subroutine will close the excel file again, so other people of my team could access it without my holding up the file. Then, I would like to refresh all the pivot tables linked to the query. Since it links to password locked file, I don't want to refresh that query again. In one of your RefreshQueries suggestion stated such a code:

```
Sub RefreshQueries()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
            qt.Refresh
        Next qt
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

You mentioned that I could write a similar subroutine to be called for updating Pivot Tables separately. Please advise how the other subroutine should be written.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following subroutine. It iterates over all the worksheets in the Workbook and then refreshes every pivotTable in the worksheet:

```vb
Sub RefreshPivotTables()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next pt
    Next ws
End Sub
```